# PHP multi-variables assignment for "key => value" array

Tags: php, arrays, list, variables, variable-assignment

PHP's `list` keyword is nice for taking out variables from an array $a as below

```
    $a = array(1,22);
    list($b, $c) = $a;
    var_dump("$a $b $c");
```

But for array $a2 in the form of `key => value` as below, I failed to use `list`

```
    $a2 = array('b'=>1,'c'=>22);
    list($b, $c) = $a2;
    list($bkey, $b, $ckey, $c) = $a2;
    list( list($bkey, $b), list($ckey,$c) ) = $a2;

    var_dump("$a2 $b $c");
```

All of the three above assignments fail. I give up.

If you know how to get the key & value in array $a2, please help!

Comment: Better suited as a comment: *list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.* [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment of Mr Evil below (Col Shrapnel, see his profile), I never said following two ways are different, one could use either but I have advised using these methods on user-inputted data could create security problems, use it on your own risk or if there is no user-inputted data.

---

It does not seem to work with associatieve arrays, you can do something like this though:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     $$key = $value;
}
```

**Example:**

```
$a2 = array('b'=>1,'c'=>22);
foreach ($a2 as $key => $value) {
     $$key = $value;
}

echo $b . '<br>';
echo $c;
```

**Result:**

```
1
22
```

---

One could also use [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function but I generally avoid it because using it on user-inputted values could create security hazards. Depending on your choice, you might want to use it or if data isn't coming from users side.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Mind your language, you idiot, ignorant ! This person has always created problems for all here, see his profile what he says. He should be banned here.

Comment: @Sarfraz, you worked only 1 year and become a senior engineer ? That's great. :-D

Comment: @Mackintoast: Worked for one year ? I don't get it?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Do you ever see other people speaking like you? Even if one answers wrong, people don't behave like you do. This is the first time I spoke like that in a comment because it is too much now, we can't bear you any more.

Comment: To: Sarfraz Agree! @Shrapnel It is not a nonsense at all!

Answer (score 1):

it seems it is `extract()` function you need

Comment: You might want to add a link or explain the function to help others struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use each function.

each() Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor.